Increase in tension due to weight
Suppose string is hanging from two hooks. We now add a weight $W$ to its midpoint the string will bend and the resulting tension in the string will be given by $W/2cos \theta$ where $\theta$ is the angle from vertical as shown in a diagram in the post If two hooks support weights on a string across a span, how much weight can it support?.
What is the relation of this tension with the original tension $T_0$ in the string (when no weight was added)? Will the horizontal component of tension $T sin \theta$ have any relation to $T_0$?

$T_0$ could be any value greater than or equal to $0$. You can see this by setting $W=0$ and $\theta = 90^o$. Then you get $T = 0/0$, which is an undetermined value.

Thank you for the reply

The origonal tension is due to the weight of the string itself, so (obviously)  indepdendent of $W$. Why do you think there should be a relation? (At least, the string angles are determined the length of the string is each case, but not in the same way.)

You can also factor in gravity to be more precise, although it is not much of an effect in most cases.

Please use MathJax in separate lines

There is no relationship between $T_0$ and resulting tension due to weight. $T_0$ depends only on the weight of the string (0 in ideal cases). So, there is no relationship.
I am sure that helps.

Yes, it helps. Thank you

Please verify if it did.
